# ADF - Client Listener with JavaScript surrounded by a button have a delay

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I have a fragment page (jsff) with a numeric keyboard based on buttons surrounded by a client listener which invoke a java script function; every time I click a number it refresh an input text with the value concatenated. I implemented that with JavaScript. Why with JavaScript? Because of the delay using partial triggers showing the value in the input text.

When I test it in the server it works very fine. I click every button and do have a little delay, but It works for the requirements of the develop.

Now, when I insert that fragment inside another jsff which have several components, the result isn't the same. I click every button, and the value is displayed in the input text very fast, but, the button I clicked takes between one and two second to reload for been clicked again. I don't understand what is happening.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle Community I was helped by Florin Marcus:

I quote the answer that works for me:

"Probably you are still propagating the event to the server. You can easily double-check this with a  browser plugin like Firefox/Firebug, see if there is any server request being sent.

Normally, you will need to explicitly cancel the event from propagating to the server. For example, if you have a clientListener on a button, you do something like below:

```
function showPopupFromAction(actionEvent)
{
  actionEvent.cancel();
//your logic here

}
```

"